# How To: Custom Product Listing Page Shopware 6

Tags: symfony, twig, shopware, shopware6

i want to create a custom page in Shopware 6 which includes the sidebar filter block. 1.st i created the controller with a custom route which loads index.html.twig. The index file extends from the default storefront index file which extends from base.html.twig.
In my index.html.twig file i included the file @Storefront/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig but this file is empty in my tpl.
i think this is the wrong way to reuse the filter.
Do you have any idea to figure it out?

Thx for your time

1. Controller with custom Route

   ```
   $page = $this->genericPageLoader->load($request, $scontext);

   return $this->renderStorefront('@DRGeolocation\storefront\index.html.twig', [
        'page' => $page,
        'range' => 15,
        'sellers'=> $sellers,
        'config' => $config['config']
        ,
        'block'=> $element
    ]);
   ```

index.html.twig

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/content/index.html.twig' %}
  {% block page_content_blocks %}
  ...
  {% sw_include ('@Storefront/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig') %}
  ....
```

cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig

```
{% block block_sidebar_filter %}
{% set element = block.slots.getSlot('content') %}
{% set columns = 1 %}

<div class="col-12" data-cms-element-id="{{ element.id }}">
    {% block block_sidebar_filter_inner %}
        {% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/element/cms-element-" ~ element.type ~ ".html.twig" ignore missing %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

//result: <div class="col-12" data-cms-element-id=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the block is empty if you include the cms-block in twig, is because it will have an empty `element` variable from `block.slots.getSlot('content')` (line 2 on `storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig`).

Since the `blocks` variable is not set if you include the template from a custom twig template, `element` is empty and nothing is shown.

This can be fixed by just including the desired inner twig template in your custom twig-template, for example the category-navigation:

```
{% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/element/cms-element-category-navigation.html.twig" %}
```